# How to extract only a specific value from a local JSON file?

Tags: json, delphi, delphi-xe7

I have a file `info.json` which contains only this code:

```json
{"personal": {"path": "C:\\My Directory", "honk": 82641923}}
```

In Delphi XE7, how can I extract the path value, i.e. `'C:\My Directory'`?

Comment: You need to choose a JSON library first, then read its documentation. Double back slash looks wrong.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The double back-slash is used to escape the second back-slash, which otherwise would be interpreted as an escape character for the "M" afterwards. Don't have an answer yet though.

Comment: @fond Once the value has been extracted I mean.

Comment: So how could one JSON-encode a local Windows path if Double back slash is not allowed?

Comment: @user when encoded the backslash is escaped. Anyway, you need to choose a library and read its docs. Which library are you keen on?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Gotcha. OP, You could use a forward-slash. Windows tends to use these in their GUI more often. Back-slashes are targeted more for the command-line and developers.

Comment: @fond Escaped backslash is correct in the JSON. I edited the question to be clear.

Comment: @fond42518 David is trying to say that the value `C:\My Directory` is inside the json string `{"value":"C:\\My Directory"}` and therefore it is **not possible** to get the value `C:\\My Directory` from the json string, because **that value** is **not inside**

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Isn't the first backslash used to escape the second backslash? So the string result from parsing would be `C:\My Directory`. - I would like to use the most simple, easy and quick to learn JSON lib for this purpose. Which one would you recommend?

Comment: @SirRufo Yeah, I understand. I get the concept of escaping. That's what I stated in the second comment. Once the string value for "path" is interpreted, the actual value doesn't contain the double-backslash, which is just an escaped character.

Comment: @user1580348 It's impossible to tell. First of all, are you using VCL or Firemonkey?

Comment: The obvious choice is the built in library: System.JSON. It is documented. There have been a gazillion questions here on this topic.

Comment: That's the first of many possible questions to be clear what you're looking for. You need to choose one yourself based on what you're trying to do.

Comment: @JerryDodge Is there any JSON library (internal or external) depending on the graphical presentation framework (VCL/FMX). And I can't see any request for painting the JSON

Comment: @SirRufo Depends on the desired usage. If you choose to use what's built-in to Delphi, it's flexible across other places in Delphi. However if you choose a library such as SuperObject/XSuperObject (platform specific difference), then it will be an entirely different story. SuperObject only works with Windows (originally VCL), then XSuperObject was introduced for Firemonkey (or in general cross-platform) support. Although the classic SuperObject isn't actually VCL, it was designed in a similar manner (for Windows).

Comment: @JerryDodge I use internal JSON and SuperObject in VCL, FMX and even console applications. There is **not a bit** in each of them that is related to VCL or FMX.

Comment: @Jerry You are wide of the mark here. JSON libraries don't need to be tied to frameworks. None of the libraries I've encountered are. SuperObject is agnostic of framework, for example.

Comment: @JerryDodge XSuperObject is **CrossPlatform** (see the cross "X" in front) and that is for use inside iOS, OSX, Android and Windows applications. But it has nothing to do with the graphical framework

Comment: I never said the library was bound to a framework. In fact I said they're **not** specific to one. My point was depending on your choice of framework, you may want to choose one or the other. That's actually my entire point, is that `SuperObject` was designed before Firemonkey was around, for Windows. If you're using Firemonkey and other platforms, obviously you would need to choose one which works cross-platform. Otherwise, if you're using VCL, you can get away with a parser that only works with Windows.

Comment: @Jerry Not really. Framework is not relevant to this choice.

Comment: @user So, you need to read this: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/JSON although the person who wrote the example code doesn't know delphi well enough to have been entrusted with the task and there appears to be no QA process at Emba. Quite what they imagine the assignment of nil is about baffles me. Can't they find people with skill to write this stuff? Don't they check it before publishing? Pfft.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks, I will study that one and the System.JSON documentation. BTW, I wonder why they don't hire you - they really should!

Comment: Not really. What they need to do is give more support to their juniors and teach them better.

Comment: I have answered this here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/82366/get-local-dropbox-path-with-delphi-xe7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a [MongoDB connector I made](https://github.com/stijnsanders/TMongoWire), I needed a light-weight JSON (actually BSON) object, and chose to base it on `OleVariant` variables. Using `JsonToBson` from `bsonUtils.pas` (and `IBSONDocument` from `bsonDoc.pas`) you could write:

```
(IUnkown(JsonToBson('{"personal": {"path": "C:\\My Directory", "honk": 82641923}}')['personal']) as IBSONDocument)['path']
```